# List with multiple strings to excel file

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, xlwt

I have a list of reactions, lets call it A

A = ['ABC+B->C+D', 'EGF(+)+F+G->I+J+K', '2000~XLM+Y->2~Q']

I wanna write an excel file where every reactant and product are in the different cell, while have stochiometric constant in front. For example

[image]

First I need to separate strings by delimiters like --> and +, how do I add 1 in front of reactant if it doesnt have a number in front? Is it better to write with pandas or xlwt?

thanks for you help!

```
import xlwt
wb = xlwt.Workbook()
ws = wb.add_sheet('Test')
new_list= []
for j in reaction:
   j = j.split ('--->')
   new_list.append(j)  
for j in new_list:
    for i in range(1, 180):
        ws.write(i,0, j[0:i]) 
        ws.write(i,1, j[i:2])
```

I know its hard, because there is (+) in an element which can not be seperated. Im thinking maybe to convert every thing to its own string and just find delimiters we want and seperate them? I edited the code again, it gives me thngs I want, but it says that its overwriting same cell, which I dont know why, cause iterate throught 1, 180 and from strings in list??? If I get this loop to work, Ill be close enough to edit the code in excel manually.

Comment: How did these reactions end up there in the first place? Assuming that all metabolites are single letters, you can just check whether the length is equal to 1 and if so add a 1 in front. A more generic way would be to test whether it starts with a number using a regular expression and add a 1 if not.

Comment: I just wanna know who to write 100000 reactions I have in python list to excel so each reactant and each product are in their own cell with "-->" between. nothing more.

Comment: `Q` doesn't have a number in front, it has `~`. If there is any rule, please post it too.

Comment: Theres not I just want each value in separate cell. I can delete that ~ in excel. It doesnt even have to be 1 in front, I can add them afterwards, just want to write excel where each value is in separate cell and then next reaction is in the next row, each value again in separate cell etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

Editing my answer...hope this helps

```
import re
import xlwt

def write_data(row,col,data,sheet):
    #groups = data.split('+')
    groups = re.split(r"\+(?!\))",data) #split on '+', but dont split if the + is followed by a ')' like in (+)
    for g in groups:
        digits_match = re.match(r'[0-9]+',g)
        if digits_match is None: #doesnt start with a digit
            digit = 1
            index = 0
        else:
            digit = digits_match.group() #take all digits
            index = len(digit)
        sheet.write(row,col,int(digit))
        col+=1
        sheet.write(row,col,g[index:])
        col+=1
    return col

book = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet = book.add_sheet('reactions')
row = 0
A = ['A+B--->4C+D', 'E(+)+F+3G--->I+J+KLM', 'X+Y--->2~Q', 'ABC+B--->C+D', '4EGF(+)+F+G--->I+J+K', '2000~XLM+Y--->2~Q']
for reaction in A:
    reaction = reaction.replace('~','') # assuming u dont need this character
    #add any other chars here if reqd...#
    col = 0
    splits = reaction.split('--->')
    col = write_data(row,col,splits[0],sheet)
    sheet.write(row,col,'--->')
    col += 1
    col = write_data(row,col,splits[1],sheet)
    row += 1
book.save('temp1.xls')
```

Comment: Not working, cause it separates them invidvidualy not just by + and -> but internal as well. If I have Glc it become 'G', 'L', 'C'.

Comment: Ah okay! haven't thought of that. Can you post some real examples that cover all the conditions/rules?

Comment: Did, sorry about that I didnt think the things through as well :(

Comment: So there s no minus sign in the reactions?

Comment: theres --->(to seperate product and reactants) and + in the reactant.

Comment: I added my code, where I am pretty close to a result and I can just manually seperate in excel

Comment: Its not completely correct but I can just correct stuff by hand. Thanks!